# Order of iterating Javascript object properties?

Tags: javascript

If I have this code :

```
o["a"]=1;
o["b"]=1;
o["c"]=1;
o["d"]=1;


for (var k in o)
{
  alert(k)
}
```

- Would it *always*(cross browser) be alerted in the same order as  the attribute were added ?
- And what about this ? (same question)

  `var o={a:1,b:1,c:1,d:1}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The order is not specified. From [the spec](http://es5.github.com/#x12.6.4):

> The mechanics **and order** of enumerating the properties ... is **not specified**.