# Json object sort by ascending using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json object and i want to sort it by ascending order

```
  [{ d: "delte the text" }, { c: "copy the text" }]
```

The key `d` and `c` are dynamically created, next time may be changed. How I can sort this into

```
[{ c: "copy the text" }, { d: "delte the text" }]
```

Please help me how I can do this.
Thanks!

Comment: Ascending order of what? Key or value?

Comment: properties in an object don't have particular order. You should use an array with numeric indexes should you want some specific order.

Comment: @PetrČihula: These are objects in an array though, not properties in an object.

Comment: thanks jon for ur reply.  I want to sort by key

Comment: This could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967566/order-of-iterating-javascript-object-properties

Answer (score 1):

To sort an array you use [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with an appropriate comparison function as an argument. The comparison function accepts two arguments, which in this case are expected to be objects with just a single property. You want to sort based on the name of that property.

Getting an object's property names is most convenient with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), so we have this comparison function:

```
function(x, y) { 
    var keyX = Object.keys(x)[0], 
        keyY = Object.keys(y)[0]; 

    if (keyX == keyY) return 0; 
    return keyX < keyY ? -1 : 1;
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
var input = [{ d: "delete the text" }, { c: "copy the text" } ];
var sorted = input.sort(function(x, y) { 
    var keyX = Object.keys(x)[0], 
        keyY = Object.keys(y)[0]; 

    if (keyX == keyY) return 0; 
    return keyX < keyY ? -1 : 1;
});
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/cEFg3/)**.

Note that `Object.keys` requires a reasonably modern browser (in particular, IE version at least 9); otherwise you would need to write something such as this instead:

```
var keyX, keyY, name;
for (name in x) { keyX = name; break; }
for (name in y) { keyY = name; break; }
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/fFRTD/)**.

Comment: The `break` is actually not necessary since it only would work reliable on one-key-objects anyway :-)

Comment: @Bergi: True! Habit of "not doing more than you need". :-)